# addOnItemTouchListener or setOnClickListener on item in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

Which is the most recommended way of handling click on `RecyclerView` items?

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    private RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener itemTouchListener;

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent) {}

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {}
});
```

Or setting a click listener on an item view inside the adapter?

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: In generally it is better to handle set the OnItemTouchListener, that way you do not have to bind the listener to every view in the recyclerview, should be more efficient. (Remember you reuse the views)

Comment: Most common way it to use interfaces to handle onClick events inside a Recycler View.
[Great read about this topic here](https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9)

Comment: Go for your second opinion. But an interface should be implemented to handle the OnClick Event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Best and efficient way to get a click of recycler view item is by **using interface** as below:

1) First, define one interface as below

```
public interface OnListItemClick {
   void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

2) Now, set it from your fragment or activity

```
OnListItemClick onListItemClick = new OnListItemClick() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                              // you will get click here 
                                // do your code here
                             }
                          };
youradaptor.setClickListener(onListItemClick);
```

3) Now create one method in your adapter

```
public void setClickListener(OnListItemClick context) {
    this.onListItemClick = context;
}
```

4) Now, from your itemview click use as below

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onListItemClick.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition()); // passing click to interface
        }
});
```